# How to diff top lines of two files without intermediate file

Tags: linux, bash

I have 2 big files and I want to make a diff between the top lines of each files, but i don't want to use intermediate files. I would like to do something like that :

```
diff `head -n 2000 file1.log` `head -n 2000 file2.log`
```

I remember I've done something like that a long time ago, ie. make a command like `head -n 2000 file1.log` interpreted as a file. But I don't remember how. Maybe it was another shell...
Thank you.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You're probably thinking of [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) in bash.  For example, try:

```
 diff <(head -n 2000 file1.log) <(head -n 2000 file2.log)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I am getting syntax error on running this `diff <(head -n 1 file1.logt) <(head -n 1 file2.log)`.
**-sh: syntax error near unexpected token`('**

Comment: @AbhiNickz Which shell are you using?

Comment: `echo $0` gives me **-sh**

Comment: So I checked again on this different shell (**-bash**) and it is working but How do I get this working on **-sh**?

Comment: I think process substitution only works on bash, ksh and zsh, I'm afraid, so if you have to use a Bourne shell then I think you're limited to doing this in multiple commands (e.g. writing to two securely created temporary files, running the command, removing them)